# Image Encryption in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, encryption, swift3

I am using `IDZSwiftCommonCrypto` for image encryption using StreamCryptor described as an example at its GitHub page: https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZSwiftCommonCrypto

I am not able to successfully decrypt. Here is my code for encryption and decryption (imageData comes from `UIImageView`). The output is different from input after encryption (imageData is different from xx).

**Encryption:**

```
func performImageEncryption(imageData: Data) -> Void {

        var inputStream = InputStream(data: imageData)

        let key = arrayFrom(hexString: "2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c")

        var sc = StreamCryptor(operation:.encrypt, algorithm:.aes, options:.PKCS7Padding, key:key, iv:Array<UInt8>())

        var inputBuffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating:0, count:1024)
        var outputBuffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating:0, count:1024)

        inputStream.open()

        var cryptedBytes = 0

        var xx = Data()

        var count = 0

        while inputStream.hasBytesAvailable
        {
            count = count + 1024
            let bytesRead = inputStream.read(&inputBuffer, maxLength: inputBuffer.count)
            let status = sc.update(bufferIn: inputBuffer, byteCountIn: bytesRead, bufferOut: &outputBuffer, byteCapacityOut: outputBuffer.count, byteCountOut: &cryptedBytes)

            xx.append(contentsOf: outputBuffer)
        }

        let status = sc.final(bufferOut: &outputBuffer, byteCapacityOut: outputBuffer.count, byteCountOut: &cryptedBytes)


        xx.append(contentsOf: outputBuffer)


        inputStream.close()

        performImageDecryption(encryptedImageData: xx)


    }
```

**Decryption:**

```
func performImageDecryption(encryptedImageData: Data) -> Void {

        let key = arrayFrom(hexString: "2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c")

        var sc = StreamCryptor(operation:.decrypt, algorithm:.aes, options:.PKCS7Padding, key:key, iv:Array<UInt8>())

        var inputStreamD = InputStream(data: encryptedImageData)

        var inputBuffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating:0, count:1024)
        var outputBuffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating:0, count:1024)

        inputStreamD.open()

        var cryptedBytes = 0


        var xx = Data()
        while inputStreamD.hasBytesAvailable
        {
            let bytesRead = inputStreamD.read(&inputBuffer, maxLength: inputBuffer.count)
            let status = sc.update(bufferIn: inputBuffer, byteCountIn: bytesRead, bufferOut: &outputBuffer, byteCapacityOut: outputBuffer.count, byteCountOut: &cryptedBytes)
            xx.append(contentsOf: outputBuffer)
        }

        let status = sc.final(bufferOut: &outputBuffer, byteCapacityOut: outputBuffer.count, byteCountOut: &cryptedBytes)
        xx.append(contentsOf: outputBuffer)

        inputStreamD.close()

    }
```

Comment: you can use base_64 for encryption and descryption.

Comment: @IOSSingh Except for the fact that base64 isn't an encryption algorithm and provides no security whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

```
xx.append(outputBuffer, count: cryptedBytes)
```

should help.

below is sample code for picking up an encrypted image file and returning the data.

```
func decryptImage(from path:URL)-> Data? {
    var decryptData = Data()

    let sc = StreamCryptor(operation:.decrypt, algorithm:.aes, options:.PKCS7Padding, key:key, iv:iv)

    guard let encryptedInputStream = InputStream(fileAtPath: path.relativePath) else {
        return nil
    }

    var inputBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(1024))
    var outputBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(1024))

    encryptedInputStream.open()

    var cryptedBytes : Int = 0
    while encryptedInputStream.hasBytesAvailable
    {
        let bytesRead = encryptedInputStream.read(&inputBuffer, maxLength: inputBuffer.count)

        let status = sc.update(bufferIn: inputBuffer, byteCountIn: bytesRead, bufferOut: &outputBuffer, byteCapacityOut: outputBuffer.count, byteCountOut: &cryptedBytes)

        if (status != Status.success) {
        encryptedInputStream.close()
            return nil
        }

        if(cryptedBytes > 0)
        {
            decryptData.append(outputBuffer, count: cryptedBytes)
        }
    }

    let status = sc.final(bufferOut: &outputBuffer, byteCapacityOut: outputBuffer.count, byteCountOut: &cryptedBytes)
    if (status != Status.success) {
        encryptedInputStream.close()
        return nil
    }

    if(cryptedBytes > 0)
    {
        decryptData.append(outputBuffer, count: cryptedBytes)
    }
    encryptedInputStream.close()
    return decryptData
}
```

Happy coding :)